# Test class coverage varies betw Sandbox/PROD for trigger that sends an email

Tags: apex, unit-test, apex-email-service

I am having difficulty when trying to create the test class for my trigger:

```
trigger Email_Pesquisa_Mercado_account on Account (after update) {

    Map<Id,Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id, Name, 
                                                       (Select Id,Name,Price,Parcelas__c,Data_do_contrato__c,
                                                            quantity,status from Assets 
                                                               where quantity>0 AND 
                                                                  Data_do_contrato__c != null AND 
                                                                   (NOT name like 'AR -%')) 
                                                       from Account Where recordtypeid='012U00000000vYx' 
                                                              AND Id in : Trigger.New]);

    for(Account Ac : Trigger.New){
        String AssetName;
        Decimal ValorVenda;
        Decimal Parcelas;
        Date DataContrato;
        String SemEmail;
        String SemEmailprincipal;

        String Situacao;
        Situacao = ac.Situacao__c;
        if(Situacao.contains('APROVADA') && 
           Trigger.oldMap.get(ac.id).pesquisa_de_mercado__c != ac.pesquisa_de_mercado__c &&
           ac.pesquisa_de_mercado__c == '1 - Pesquisa Satisfação B2' && 
           ac.antecipado__c != 'AR' && 
           ac.antecipado__c != 'TES' && 
             (ac.turma__c == '2013 2S - UNISA - MEDICINA - SAO PAULO' || 
               ac.turma__c == '2013 2S - FAAP - ENG,ARQ,ECON,REL INT,S IN - SAO PAULO' || 
               ac.turma__c == '2013 2S - UNICID - ODONTOLOGIA - SAO PAULO')
           ){
            if(accountMap.get(Ac.Id).Assets.size() > 0){
                for(Asset obj : accountMap.get(Ac.Id).Assets){
                    if(obj.name != null){
                        if(AssetName==null){
                            AssetName = obj.Name;
                        }
                        else{
                            AssetName = AssetName + '<br> ' + ''+obj.Name+'';
                        }
                        ValorVenda = obj.Price;
                        Parcelas = obj.Parcelas__c;    
                        DataContrato = obj.Data_do_contrato__c.addDays(90);
                    }
                }

                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                String[] toAddresses = new String[]{};              
                if(ac.PersonEmail == null){
                    SemEmailprincipal = 'sememail@b2agencia.com.br';
                }
                if(ac.PersonEmail != null){
                    SemEmailprincipal = ac.PersonEmail;
                }                       

                toAddresses.add(SemEmailprincipal);               
                if(ac.Email_alternativo__c == null ){
                    SemEmail = 'sememail@b2agencia.com.br';
                }
                if(ac.Email_alternativo__c != null){
                    SemEmail = ac.Email_alternativo__c;
                }               
                toAddresses.add(SemEmail);               
                mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

                mail.setreplyto('foto.filmagem@b2agencia.com.br');
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('B2 Agência');

                mail.setSubject('B2 Foto e Filmagem: Seu álbum de formatura');
                mail.setHtmlBody('Olá, '+ac.FirstName+' '+ac.LastName+'<p>Primeiramente gostaríamos de parabenizá-lo pela conquista da sua formatura, sabemos que é um grande marco para o início da sua vida profissional. Desejamos que você tenha muito sucesso em sua caminhada!<p>Para guardar todas essas recordações, você efetuou a compra dos produtos abaixo:<p>'+AssetName+'<p>O valor total da sua compra é de R$ '+ValorVenda+', parcelado em '+Parcelas+' vezes.<p>Os produtos extras serão entregues até o dia '+DataContrato.day()+'/'+DataContrato.month()+'/'+DataContrato.year()+', no '+ac.Cidade__c+' - RUA '+ac.Endereco__c+', '+ac.Nro__c+'<p>O envio dos mesmos é feito pelo correio, que faz 3 tentativas de entrega. Caso o correio não consiga efetuar a entrega nas 3 tentativas, o produto volta para o escritório e vamos aguardar o seu contato nos informando um novo endereço de entrega.<p><font color="#EE7600"><b>PREOCUPADO COM A SATISFAÇÃO DE NOSSOS CLIENTES, BUSCAMOS PROMOVER MELHORIAS CONTÍNUAS EM NOSSOS SERVIÇOS E PRODUTOS, PARA ISSO, A SUA OPINIÃO É MUITO IMPORTANTE!<p>TIRE 2 MINUTINHOS DO SEU DIA PARA RESPONDER À NOSSA PESQUISA DE SATISFAÇÃO</font></b> <a href=http://sistemaff.force.com/B2/TIMBASURVEYS__Survey?id=a0UU0000005UKnaMAG&pAccId='+ac.id+'&wf=yes><font color="#458B00"><b>CLICANDO AQUI</b></font></a>.</p><br>Obrigado!<br><a href=http://sistemaff.force.com/B2/TIMBASURVEYS__Survey?id=a0UU0000005UKnaMAG&pAccId='+ac.id+'&wf=yes><img src="https://na12.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015U0000002G2fd&oid=00DU0000000KBJn" alt="B2"/>');

                Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get 91%, but when I will deploy in my production appears to me 74%.

```
@istest(seealldata=true)
public class Email_Pesquisa_Mercado_test{
    static testmethod void unittest(){

   String AssetName;
   Decimal ValorVenda;
   Decimal Parcelas;
   Date DataContrato;
   String SemEmail;
   String SemEmailprincipal;

        Turma__c t=new Turma__c();
            t.name = '2013 2S - UNISA - MEDICINA - SAO PAULO';
            t.PIT__c = 'US000112';
        insert t;

        Product2 p=new Product2();
            p.Name = 'DVD';
        insert p;        

        Account acc=new Account();
            acc.FirstName = 'ANDREA';
            acc.LastName = 'SOLFERINI MORAES BARROS';
            acc.ID_do_formando__c = 'CP7_5011_000008';
            acc.Cidade__c = 'SÃO PAULO';
            acc.Endereco__c = 'RUA PHILIPP LOHBAUER';
            acc.Nro__c = '330';
            acc.turma__c = t.id;
            acc.pesquisa_de_mercado__c = null;
            acc.antecipado__c = null;
            acc.recordtypeid='012U00000000vYx';
            acc.PersonEmail = 'sememail@b2agencia.com.br';
            acc.Email_alternativo__c = 'sememail@b2agencia.com.br';
        insert acc;

        Asset a=new Asset();       
         a.name = p.id;
         a.Price = 100;
         a.Parcelas__c = 1;
         a.data_do_contrato__c = date.today();
         a.accountId = acc.id;
         a.quantity = 1;
         a.pesquisa_de_mercado__c = null;
        insert a;

         AssetName = a.Name;   
         ValorVenda = a.Price;
         Parcelas = a.Parcelas__c;    
         DataContrato = a.Data_do_contrato__c.addDays(90);
         SemEmail = acc.PersonEmail;
         SemEmailprincipal = acc.Email_alternativo__c;

        update a;

            acc.FirstName = 'ANDREA';
            acc.LastName = 'SOLFERINI MORAES BARROS';
            acc.ID_do_formando__c = 'CP7_5011_000008';
            acc.Cidade__c = 'SÃO PAULO';
            acc.Endereco__c = 'RUA PHILIPP LOHBAUER';
            acc.Nro__c = '330';
            acc.turma__c = t.id;
            acc.pesquisa_de_mercado__c = '1 - Pesquisa Satisfação B2';
            acc.antecipado__c = null;
            acc.recordtypeid='012U00000000vYx';
            acc.PersonEmail = 'sememail@b2agencia.com.br';
            acc.Email_alternativo__c = 'sememail@b2agencia.com.br';
            acc.situacao__c = 'VENDA APROVADA';
        update acc;
        }
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you'd post what you've done thus far. There's example code in the APEX API for an Email messaging Service which might find helpful if you've not started your test class yet.

Comment: Could you tell which lines are not being covered ?
I remember reading somewhere that encapsulating code which creates SingleEmailMessage, populates properties and calls SendEmail in a separate class may help.

Comment: why are you using `seeAllData=true` in your test? There should be almost no reason why this is necessary and can go a long way towards explaining why you get different test coverage in prod vs sandbox

Answer (score 0):

While writing tests, the best tool I found for checking coverage is Mavensmate plugin for Sublime Text. 
It shows you a web UI to run tests and shows you a colored coding over where your test is passing and where not.
This will help you find out WHERE that % is missing coverage and you will be able to address it in your test class.
URL: http://mavensmate.com/

I know its a bit of an overhead when you're just trying to solve this issue, but it will help you a lot in the long term to have this at hand, and we could help you resolve this faster and more accurate!

Cheers!
PD: I noticed on your code there is a FOR loop that seems to be losing the state of some variables without using them anywhere, you might want to check that for a possible bug.

> ValorVenda = obj.Price;
>   Parcelas = obj.Parcelas__c;
>   DataContrato = obj.Data_do_contrato__c.addDays(90);
>   "ValorVenda", "Parcelas", and "DataContrato" will lose the previous value on each loop and they are not being saved or used anywhere.